# Good books on stochastic partial differential equations?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, differential-equations, pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems

I have a system of 2 PDEs, one with a probabilistic right side, and kind of stuck on what to read about those things.. Any good books around? Both analytical (if any) and numerical methods are welcome.
I have some PDE literature and some SDE literature, but need to figure out SPDEs... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the analytical side, I like a lot the book [A Concise Course on Stochastic Partial Differential Equations](http://books.google.com/books?id=Q-JDooJbjCAC&pg=PP4&dq=prevot+roeckner&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9dc_Ub_zIK214AOI9YHwDw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA) by Prevot and Roeckner. It is a very well written introduction to SPDEs.

Besides this, I know a couple of people who are very fond of [Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions](http://books.google.com/books?id=JYiL8zz_nC8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=da+prato+zabczyk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=89g_Ud_JB4vj4AOLy4GAAQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA) by da Prato and Zabczyk.